# translations don't export correctly from blender to source (with source tools)

Tags: animation

When i try to export a blender animation to smd with the [blender source tools](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Blender_Source_Tools), and then open the animation in the dota workshop tools, the rotation takes place, but the translations do not. Making the animation look really weird.

The animation shows fine in blender, i have applied LocRotScale to every keyframe, but it appears only the rotational information gets exported.

Is there a known solution to this problem?

EDIT: the translations do get exported, but their scale is so small that its barely visible

EDIT2: for anyone with similar issues, i fixed it by selecting te object together with its armature, applying scale and reexporting the object and its animations.

Comment: My guess is it's a scale issue.  Scaling does not affect rotation. What blender unit dimensions (roundabouts) are your objects.  Do they have non unity scale.?

Comment: i'm sorry but i do not know how to check this. I can see that under Transform for Scale, it says x:1.000 y:1.000 z:1.000, is that what u mean?

Comment: for length it has "none" and for angles it has "degrees", unit scale is locked to 1.000